# como puedo enviar estos dos valores "action" , "consultar" usando webservice mediante fluter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

hola estoy aprendiente hacer webservice mediante flutter y quiero enviar 2 cadenas de texto ejemplo: "action","consultar", ya que mi backend esta esperando una accion y tipo de la acccion que se va hace, ya habia hecho algo asi en android estudio, pero no se como hacerlo en flutter ya que ando aprnediendo, si alguien me puede orientar.

cabe de mencionar que aplico lo de data, y lo mando a llamar en el body, pero en mi app nada mas me muestras un spinnner que anda cargando los datos y de ahi no pasa, ya rebice mi backend y esta bien mediante postma

este es mi codigo

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:primera_app/modelo/estudiante_modelo.dart';

class estudianteControlador{
  //crea la lista mediante un array del modelo y conviertelo en strinj de objeto jsonstring
  List<estudianteModelo> estudiantesFromJson(String jsontring){
    final datos = jsonDecode(jsontring);//decodifica el json
    //regresa como lista de arra el modelo de los datos mapeados de item con estudaindremodelo de json como item
    return List<estudianteModelo>.from(datos.map((item)=>estudianteModelo.FromJson(item)));

  }
  String accionConsulta = "consultar";
  String a = "action";

  //creando el metodo para hacer el webservice
  Future<List<estudianteModelo>> getEstudiantes() async{
    var url = Uri.parse("http://192.168.100.11/escuela/controlador/alumnos.php"); //link de donde se encuentra nuestro archivo php
    var   data = {
      "action": "action",
      "consultar": "consultar",
    };

    var response = await http.post(url, body: data); //haciendo la conexion con la url peticion http

    //si la respuerta de la peticion es correcta ejecuta if si no else
    if(response.statusCode == 200 ){
      //accediento a la lista mediante el modelo nombrando una variable list de estufromjson con response mediante body
      List<estudianteModelo> list = estudiantesFromJson(response.body);
      return list;//si es correcto regresame con return como la variable list
    }else{
      return <estudianteModelo>[];
    }
  }

}
```